# Oauth with Sharepoint, Azure AD B2C and a C# Consumer

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

We have a .NET 4.7.2 web application (Auth) that is used as our central source of authentication, with local accounts that are stored on-prem in our MsSql db. User identity is persisted with encrypted, chunked cookies, with the keys stored in Azure blobs and protected at rest by Azure Key Vault. We have five applications that use this site to authenticate, sharing the cookies between them. They vary from .NET Framework 4.5 to .NET 7.

We're doing a rewrite from an old Sharepoint site to .NET 6, and the rewrite now uses our Auth scheme. However, we can't just force clients onto the new system all-at-once, we don't want users to create multiple accounts, and we need to be seamless for login. We've chosen Azure AD B2C as a way to federate identity between all of the different applications.

The flow is expected to be that a user clicks on a Tableau report link - this could be from an email, in Sharepoint, or a link they've bookmarked. Since they're not logged into the Auth application at this time and thus have no cookies or user identity, they would be redirected to the Auth app for authentication. We don't want them to have to maintain two different accounts, though, so we would ask them how they want to authenticate:

- Sign in with a local account
- Use SSO (SAML) to connect to their client's ADFS
- Log in using their existing Sharepoint account

The first two options already exist in our Auth application. The third would be new.

If they choose the Sharepoint account, the flow would be:

- Request to Azure AD B2C using oauth for a token for identity
- Azure Ad B2C sends the user to Sharepoint to log in (or if they're already logged in, recognizes that and their account)
- Azure Ad B2C returns to our application a token (I assume JWT) containing the user id, email, username, and other pertinent details
- We either generate a shell account with these details, or locate an existing one from the last time and log the user in
- User is able to now view reports for the lifetime of the cookies/browser session

I am at a loss exactly where to start here. I've spent most of the day reviewing all sorts of OAuth libraries for C# but none seem to be what I'd need to *consume* a token on our end to generate an account/identity to store in our cookies.

Anyone have experience with this scenario and can point me to any code samples or the right library to implement, in our Auth application, being able to consume a token with a specific format that I can use to generate shell accounts or log a user in without a password? I don't need help generating the accounts or claims/identity - plenty of experience there - I just have no idea where to start with OAuth and C#.

Thanks!

I've reviewed a number of OAuth Libraries and code samples that seem to be based on us being an OAuth Provider/Server.